# Yahoo options chain pricing vs stock broker pricing

Tags: options, finance, algorithmic-trading, yahoofinance

I am having hard time understanding the price difference of yahoo option chains.

For example:
Yahoo shows for TWTR FEB 17, 2017 CALL @16.50 option

```
Strike Last Price    Bid      Ask
16.50    0.10          0.09   0.10
```

Whereas at a stock broker (ex: tastyworks)
for TWTR FEB 17, 2017 CALL @16.50 option

```
Strike    Bid    Ask
16.50     0.30   0.31
```

Whereas at a stock broker (ex: thinkorswim)
for TWTR FEB 17, 2017 CALL @16.50 option

```
Strike    Bid    Ask
16.50     0.28   0.29
```

I can understand the difference between thinkorswim vs tastyworks but not yahoo. Where does the difference between comes from ?
Is yahoo delayed ? If that's the case why people bother reading yahoo options?

Comment: Yahoo's data is >=15minutes delayed, e.g. `TWTR170217C00016500` says `OPR - OPR Delayed price`.

Comment: See http://finance.yahoo.com/exchanges?bypass=true There's a `Sign up for the Real-time Package.` option

Comment: there goes the pandas data reader option. Any suggestions for options algo trading? @rbm